# ordering sql results from IN() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT categories_id
     , categories_name
     ,categories_url
FROM categories
WHERE categories_id IN(0,72,51,52)
```

For the `IN` function I have the numbers 0,72,51,52, but when I get the sql results they are 0,51,52,72, i.e. chronological. How can I order them the same way there were originally as 0,72,51,52?

Comment: I don't see any `order by` in your query then how come you are getting an order?

Comment: By default, most databases will give you the most efficient ordering of items, which often shows up as primary key order or insertion order. I believe to sort by an arbitrary list like that you'd have to handle sorting yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [`field`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) in the `order by` clause:

```
order by field(categories_id, 0, 72, 51, 52)
```